#  Reference for Almost-Kahler geometry 

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, riemannian-geometry, symplectic-topology

Is there any comprehensive reference for Almos-Kahler geometry or more generally to Almost- Hermitian geometry ?

Comment: I added some more tags. I know 'complex geometry' is not strictly speaking appropriate here, but people who approach complex geometry from the differential-geometric viewpoint (such as me) are interested in almost Kahler manifolds or in almost Hermitian manifolds in general.

Answer (score 5):

The paper that started this all is the one by Gray and Hervella where they classified the different types of almost Hermitian structures.  It's a classic and still very much well worth reading:

The sixteen classes of almost Hermitian manifolds and their linear invariants.

A Gray, LM Hervella.

Ann. Mat. Pura Appl. (4) (1980) vol. 123 pp. 35-58

http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publications.html?pg1=MR&s1=MR581924

Comment: Thank you for your help. Now I understood what I want to study.

Answer (score 3):

A slightly more current paper can be found here:

Apostolov, Vestislav; Drăghici, Tedi
The curvature and the integrability of almost-Kähler manifolds: a survey. Symplectic and contact topology: interactions and perspectives (Toronto, ON/Montreal, QC, 2001), 25–53, 
Fields Inst. Commun., 35, Amer. Math. Soc., Providence, RI, 2003.

This gives a review of the various approaches to Almost Kaehler Geometry that has been taken since the Gray/Hervella article.